# How can I make the Recorder Toolbar stay visible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, toolbar, visual-studio-macros, recorder

I can make the Recorder Toolbar appear on my Visual Studio toolbar by right-clicking the toolbar, selecting 'Customize', then selecting 'Recorder', but the toolbar always get's removed when I stop recording.

I believe this is a side-effect of the default behavior, which only shows the toolbar when you are recording, but I want to use the toolbar to *start* recording.

How can I make the recorder toolbar stay visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can.  Fixable another way though.  Tools + Customize, Commands tab.  Select Toolbar and pick a toolbar you have always visible.  Like Standard.  Select the place where you want to insert in the lower left Controls panel.  Add Command, Tools, select "Record TemporaryMacro", OK.

You'll now always have it available to start recording a macro.